# AttributeError: 'GraphAPI' object has no attribute 'search'

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to apply this code:

```
 users = graph.search(type='user',q='Mark Zuckerberg')
 for user in users['data']:
 print('%s %s' % (user['id'],user['name'].encode()))
```

from this link: http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

in the python script  and I'm getting this error "AttributeError: 'GraphAPI' object has no attribute 'search'"

any help with this would be very appreciated because I searched online and on StackOverflow I got nothing.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How was your `graph` object instantiated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out its a version issue not an error, search is valid after facebook sdk  version 2.0.0